# Qt installation on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, qt

I have a problem with the installation of Qt, I have this error:

> The procedure entry point _dsign could not be located in the dynamic link library

My OS is Windows 8.1 64 bits and I downloaded this executable : `qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2015_64-5.6.0.exe`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you try with the [online installer](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/qt-unified-windows-x86-online.exe)?

Comment: Yes, it's the same

Comment: Well, it's not the same actually. You're using the offline installer.

Comment: Yes, but I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You are downloading Qt for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, as it is said in your .exe : `msvc2015`. Are you sure you are using this version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes I have Visual Studio 2015 Professional

Comment: Is there a name for the dynamic link library?

Comment: No, just the name of entry: _dsign

Comment: Strange, usually these errors appear when a .dll is missing, so the name of the dynamic librabry should be displayed..

Comment: So this happens when you launch the .exe? Seems like the .exe itself is not working, that's weird

Comment: Yes, it's happen when I launch the exe